# Can you edit the lightning edit page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, custom, edit

I want to make custom changes to the lightning edit page. Is this possible?

I want to put a look up field to a junction object on the edit page. My developer brain goes straight to "is there a lightning component I can update?" but I am not finding the page nor is there a reference to the page name in the URL. So perhaps there is a declarative way to update?

or maybe it is not possible at all and I would have to overwrite the entire edit page.

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: As long as this is out of the box, Edit page is guided by the page layout. So as long as you have the lookup field created on the object and added on the page layout, you will be able to view that on your edit page.

Comment: I need to be able to add multiple of the junction record so a look up wouldn't work (one to one).

Comment: You will then need to build something custom here. There's nothing available out of the box (or any other component that I as far as know of).

Comment: thank you for confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

As Jayant said in the comments - I will need to create a custom component from scratch. There is no way to edit the edit page with declarative tools.